# Display Multiple Record values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two tables like

```
      ID     Name
       1      XYZ
       2      PQR

       ID    Value
        1     X
        2     Y
        1     P
        2     Q
```

I need the output as follows in my `SSRS` report

```
              XYZ     PQR
               X       y
               P       Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a stored procedure to generate a "join" on the "ID" column. Then use the stored procedure as the datasource for a new "Dataset" in your SSRS report.

On a sidenote, why does the report require the grouping to be laid out horizontally?

Comment: Can i have a sample query for this

Answer (score 0):

As per SP request in previous comment:

SELECT t1.Name, t2.Value
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID

Comment: But this is not giving the output as i required